# Azure devops pipeline - is it possible to download several packages from feed in one command?

Tags: azure-pipelines

as part of the pipeline we are download 4 packages, and at the moment it is one task per package, example:

```
    - task: UniversalPackages@0
      inputs:
        command: 'download'
        downloadDirectory: 'folder'
        feedsToUse: 'internal'
        vstsFeed: '<feed id>'
        vstsFeedPackage: '<feed package>'
        vstsPackageVersion: '*.*.*'
      displayName: Download package 1
      timeoutInMinutes: 5
```

is it possible to have all packages download in one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc about [UniversalPackages task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-a-universal-package).

> To download a Universal Package from a feed in your organization, use the Universal package task with the download

It only supports download a universal package at a time.

To download multiple packages in one task, you can use PowerShell task and use  [az artifacts universal download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#az-artifacts-universal-download) command to download packages.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/xx" --project "xx" --scope project --feed "feedname" --name "packagename" --version "xxx" --path .
   
   az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/org/" --project "project" --scope project --feed "feedname" --name "packagename" --version "xxx" --path .
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(system.accesstoken)
```

You can navigate to **Artifacts -> Select feed -> Select target package** and check the download command.

Comment: btw the download time take longer when using the az command, so we ended up keeping the current setting.